# Laravel Dependency Injection not working within Services

Tags: laravel, laravel-5.8

I have some services which are not able to access injected into the service:

```php
<?php

namespace App\Services\Translation;

use App\Services\Translation\Translators\AWSTranslationService;

class TranslatorService
{
  protected $awsTranslator;

  public function __contruct(AWSTranslationService $awsTranslator)
  {
      $this->awsTranslator = $awsTranslator;
  }

  public function translate($text, $lang, $translator = 'aws')
  {    
      return $this->awsTranslator->translate($text, $lang);
  }
}
```

Accessing `translate()` here does not work when called via Tinker/a test console command - it gives the error `Call to a member function translate() on null` on the line `return $this->awsTranslator->translate($text, $lang);`

If I replace the `translate()` code with:

```php
$trans = new AWSTranslationService();
return $trans->translate($text, $lang);
```

Then it does work. Obviously I don't want to use `new` but want to inject properly.

What's wrong here? The pattern is the same as I'm using elsewhere throughout Laravel...

Comment: How did you bind the class into the container? And how is TranslatorService instantiated?

Comment: I didn't bind it - I never have. I have over 600 services in this project and this is the first time I've had this issue. But perhaps I'm doing something different? And TranslatorService I have injected via the test commands handle() like `handle(TranslatorService $translator)` or with `new` via Tinker...

Comment: What if in tinker you do: `use App\Services\Translation\TranslatorService; $trans = resolve(TranslatorService::class); dump($trans->translate('hello', 'es'));` do you still obtain an error?

Comment: @mdexp Same error I'm afraid - `Call to member function translate() on null...` ([imgur](https://i.imgur.com/xOte9HC.png))

Comment: And for reference, AWSTranslationService does seem to work if instantiated alone with `$trans = new AWSTranslationService();` [imgur](https://i.imgur.com/TXj1C3Q.png)

Comment: What if you try to resolve the class out of the container (after the use statement to import it): `dump(resolve(AWSTranslationService::class))`

Comment: @mdexp That works and dumps `App\Services\Translation\Translators\AWSTranslationService` after `use App\Services\Translation\Translators\AWSTranslationService;`

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](https://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/197506/discussion-between-mdexp-and-samiles).

Answer (score 0):

```
public function __contruct(AWSTranslationService $awsTranslator)
{
    $this->awsTranslator = $awsTranslator;
}
```

Has a typo in construct. Should be:

```
public function __construct(AWSTranslationService $awsTranslator)
{
    $this->awsTranslator = $awsTranslator;
}
```